# Large Amount of Blacklist Checks Causes Script Timeout

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, dns, blacklist

While I've seen several other posts similar in context, none seem to be quite that helpful, so sorry if this looks like a repeat.

I'm working on a way to run a blacklist report for over 1000 IPs against about a dozen different blacklist reports. I've been working with PHP to handle the DNS querying and MySQL to hold the IPs and blacklist URLs, but, understandably, I'm running into massive request times and eventually timeouts for the processes. The SQL queries run very fast, but the breakdown is, obviously, the DNS lookup.

Is there a way I could store these requests in small chunks and handle them in a stream? I was originally thinking of using AJAX, but from my understanding it's more a browser session language and wouldn't help in a cron as I'm needing it.

Comment: Increase or remove the time limit in the `php.ini` file for CLI.

Comment: I've tried doing that, and it does work to some extent but it's still fairly slow. Is it wiser to rethink the way I'm making the DNS checks or trying to optimize the speed?

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing the code. You may be able to speed things up by caching, since there may be many repeated queries.

Comment: Good idea. I'll try that in conjunction with possibly altering my methodology. Thanks again.